# C# Regex group multiple captures

Tags: c#, regex

The following code return 1:

```
Regex.Match("aaa", "(a)").Groups[1].Captures.Count
```

But I expect to receive 3: I see three captures of a.

Comment: For capturing multiple groups use `Regex.Matches` it'll return a MatchCollection with all the matches.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You need to either get the match count:

```
Regex.Matches("aaa", "(a)").Count
```

Or add a quantifier to the regex:

```
Regex.Match("aaa", "(a)+").Groups[1].Captures.Count
```

The regex `(a)` matches only a single `a`. In the first example above, that regex can be matched three times.

In the second example the regex matches several `a`s at once and captures each one into group 1.

To make a choice you should consider the following differences between them:

```
Regex.Matches("aaba", "(a)").Count // this is 3
Regex.Match("aaba", "(a)+").Groups[1].Captures.Count // this is 2
```

The second only yields two captures because it matches the first sequence of two `a`s but then it stops matching when it finds a `b`. The `+` quantifier only matches unbroken sequences.

Answer (score 4):

Use [`Regex.Matches` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.matches.aspx) instead ?