# Using regex to match multiple times using capturing group

Tags: c#, regex, match

I am attempting to use regex matching to get a list of optional params out of an mvc route and dynamically inject values into the holders where variables have been used. See code below. Unfortunatly the sample doesn't find both values but repeats the first. Can anyone offer any help?

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace regexTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var inputstr = "http://localhost:12345/Controller/Action/{route:value1}/{route:value2}";

            var routeRegex = new Regex(@"(?<RouteVals>{route:[\w]+})");
            var routeMatches = routeRegex.Match(inputstr);

            for (var i = 0; i < routeMatches.Groups.Count; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(routeMatches.Groups[i].Value);
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

This outputs

```
{route:value1}
{route:value1}
```

where I was hopeing to get

```
{route:value1}
{route:value2}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know nothing about C# but it may help if you put the quantifier *after* the closing parenthese, no?

**Update:** [That post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4970816/c-sharp-regex-group-multiple-captures) may help you.

Comment: Could you test the simplified definition: `new Regex("({route:[\w]})+");`?

Comment: Renaud, you have solved it, thanks. The post you mentioned showed that I should be using Matches NOT Match....

            var routeMatches = routeRegex.Matches(inputstr);

            for (var i = 0; i < routeMatches.Count; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(routeMatches[i].Value);
            }

Answer (score 1):

Just make a global match :

```
    var inputstr = "http://localhost:12345/Controller/Action/{route:value1}/{route:value2}";
    StringCollection resultList = new StringCollection();
    Regex regexObj = new Regex(@"\{route:\w+\}");
    Match matchResult = regexObj.Match(inputstr);
    while (matchResult.Success) {
        resultList.Add(matchResult.Value);
        matchResult = matchResult.NextMatch();
    }
```

Your results will be stored in resultList.

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach (Match match in routeMatches){
    for(var i=1;i<match.Groups.Count;++i)
        Console.WriteLine(match.Groups[i].Value);
}
```

Comment: Hi Bluepixy, thanks for the comment. The important thing to note though is that inorder to enumerate routeMatches you have to call .Matches() not .Match() only then can you extract all the matches because Matches() returns a MatchCollection and Match() just returns a Match. You can then either query the results as you have done here or as I mentioned in my reply to Renaud.