# Regex matching chunks of multiline text?

Tags: c#, regex

I have a text file that contains over 200 records of the following format:

```
 @INPROCEEDINGS{Rajan-Sullivan03,
  author = {Hridesh Rajan and Kevin J. Sullivan},
  title = {{{Eos}: Instance-Level Aspects for Integrated System Design}},
  booktitle = {ESEC/FSE 2003},
  year = {2003},
  pages = {297--306},
  month = sep,
  isbn = {1-58113-743-5},
  location = {Helsinki, FN},
  owner = {Administrator},
  timestamp = {2009.03.08}
}

@INPROCEEDINGS{ras-mor-models-06,
  author = {Awais Rashid and Ana Moreira},
  title = {Domain Models Are {NOT} Aspect Free},
  booktitle = {MoDELS},
  year = {2006},
  editor = {Oscar Nierstrasz and Jon Whittle and David Harel and Gianna Reggio},
  volume = {4199},
  series = {Lecture Notes in Computer Science},
  pages = {155--169},
  publisher = {Springer},
  bibdate = {2006-12-07},
  bibsource = {DBLP, http://dblp.uni-trier.de/db/conf/models/models2006.html#RashidM06},
  isbn = {3-540-45772-0},
  owner = {aljasser},
  timestamp = {2008.09.16},
  url = {http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/11880240_12}
}
```

Basically a records starts with @ and ends with a }, so what i tried to do is start with @ and end with }\n} but didn't work, it will only match the first record and the other one because there is no new line after it.

```
            string pattern = @"(^@)([\s\S]*)(}$\n}(\n))";
```

and when i tried to fix it by making it, it matched everything as one match

```
 string pattern = @"(^@)([\s\S]*)(}$\n}(\n*))";
```

I have tried until i reached the following pattern but it's not working, please if you can fix it or maybe give a more efficient one plus a little explanation on it's done.

Here is my code:

```
            string pattern = @"(^@)([\s\S]*)(}$\n}(\n))";
        Regex regex = new Regex(pattern,RegexOptions.Multiline);
        var matches = regex.Matches(bibFileContent).Cast<Match>().Select(m => m.Value).ToList();
```

Comment: Be more specific about what "not working" means. Give examples of your desired output.

Comment: It matches only first record

Comment: Would this not be simpler?  
string pattern = @"@([^;]*)}";   This is a great place to play with Regex http://www.regexr.com/

Comment: Also I would suggestion using groups. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4970816/c-sharp-regex-group-multiple-captures as an example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a candidate for balanced groups.

```
 # @"(?m)^[^\S\r\n]*@[^{}]+(?:\{(?>[^{}]+|\{(?<Depth>)|\}(?<-Depth>))*(?(Depth)(?!))\})"

 (?m)
 ^ [^\S\r\n]* 
 @ [^{}]+ 
 (?:
      \{                            # Match opening {
      (?>                           # Then either match (possessively):
           [^{}]+                        #   Anything (but only if we're not at the start of { or } )
        |                              # or
           \{                            #  { (and increase the braces counter)
           (?<Depth> )
        |                              # or
           \}                            #  } (and decrease the braces counter).
           (?<-Depth> )
      )*                            # Repeat as needed.
      (?(Depth)                     # Assert that the braces counter is at zero.
           (?!)                          # Fail if it isn't
      )
      \}                            # Then match a closing }. 
 )
```

Code sample

```
Regex FghRx = new Regex( @"(?m)^[^\S\r\n]*@[^{}]+(?:\{(?>[^{}]+|\{(?<Depth>)|\}(?<-Depth>))*(?(Depth)(?!))\})" );
string FghData =
@"
@INPROCEEDINGS{Rajan-Sullivan03,
author = {Hridesh Rajan and Kevin J. Sullivan},
  title = {{{Eos}: Instance-Level Aspects for Integrated System Design}},
  booktitle = {ESEC/FSE 2003},
  year = {2003},
  pages = {297--306},
  month = sep,
  isbn = {1-58113-743-5},
  location = {Helsinki, FN},
  owner = {Administrator},
  timestamp = {2009.03.08}
}

@INPROCEEDINGS{ras-mor-models-06,
  author = {Awais Rashid and Ana Moreira},
  title = {Domain Models Are {NOT} Aspect Free},
  booktitle = {MoDELS},
  year = {2006},
  editor = {Oscar Nierstrasz and Jon Whittle and David Harel and Gianna Reggio},
  volume = {4199},
  series = {Lecture Notes in Computer Science},
  pages = {155--169},
  publisher = {Springer},
  bibdate = {2006-12-07},
  bibsource = {DBLP, http://dblp.uni-trier.de/db/conf/models/models2006.html#RashidM06},
  isbn = {3-540-45772-0},
  owner = {aljasser},
  timestamp = {2008.09.16},
  url = {http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/11880240_12}
}
";

Match FghMatch = FghRx.Match(FghData);
while (FghMatch.Success)
{
    Console.WriteLine("New Record\n------------------------");
    Console.WriteLine("{0}", FghMatch.Groups[0].Value);
    FghMatch = FghMatch.NextMatch();
    Console.WriteLine("");
}
```

Output

```
New Record
------------------------
@INPROCEEDINGS{Rajan-Sullivan03,
author = {Hridesh Rajan and Kevin J. Sullivan},
  title = {{{Eos}: Instance-Level Aspects for Integrated System Design}},
  booktitle = {ESEC/FSE 2003},
  year = {2003},
  pages = {297--306},
  month = sep,
  isbn = {1-58113-743-5},
  location = {Helsinki, FN},
  owner = {Administrator},
  timestamp = {2009.03.08}
}

New Record
------------------------
@INPROCEEDINGS{ras-mor-models-06,
  author = {Awais Rashid and Ana Moreira},
  title = {Domain Models Are {NOT} Aspect Free},
  booktitle = {MoDELS},
  year = {2006},
  editor = {Oscar Nierstrasz and Jon Whittle and David Harel and Gianna Reggio},
  volume = {4199},
  series = {Lecture Notes in Computer Science},
  pages = {155--169},
  publisher = {Springer},
  bibdate = {2006-12-07},
  bibsource = {DBLP, http://dblp.uni-trier.de/db/conf/models/models2006.html#RashidM06},
  isbn = {3-540-45772-0},
  owner = {aljasser},
  timestamp = {2008.09.16},
  url = {http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/11880240_12}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you use the Matches method, you need this kind of patterns, that deal with balanced curly brackets:

```
string pattern = @"@[A-Z]+{(?>[^{}]+|(?<open>{)|(?<-open>}))*(?(open)(?!))}";
Regex regex = new Regex(pattern);
```

or to ensure that all results are well-formed *(in a brackets point of view)*:

```
string pattern = @"\G[^{}]*(@[A-Z]+{(?>[^{}]+|(?<open>{)|(?<-open>}))*(?(open)(?!))})";
```

These two patterns use named captures as a counter. When an opening bracket is met the counter is incremented, when a closing bracket is met the counter is decremented. `(?(open)(?!))` is a conditional test that makes the pattern fail if the counter isn't null.

[online demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5CG%5B%5E%7B%7D%5D*(%40%5BA-Z%5D%2B%7B(%3F%3E%5B%5E%7B%7D%5D%2B%7C(%3F%3Copen%3E%7B)%7C(%3F%3C-open%3E%7D))*(%3F(open)(%3F!))%7D)&i=%40INPROCEEDINGS%7BRajan-Sullivan03%2C%0D%0A%20%20author%20%3D%20%7BHridesh%20Rajan%20and%20Kevin%20J.%20Sullivan%7D%2C%0D%0A%20%20title%20%3D%20%7B%7B%7BEos%7D%3A%20Instance-Level%20Aspects%20for%20Integrated%20System%20Design%7D%7D%2C%0D%0A%20%20booktitle%20%3D%20%7BESEC%2FFSE%202003%7D%2C%0D%0A%20%20year%20%3D%20%7B2003%7D%2C%0D%0A%20%20pages%20%3D%20%7B297--306%7D%2C%0D%0A%20%20month%20%3D%20sep%2C%0D%0A%20%20isbn%20%3D%20%7B1-58113-743-5%7D%2C%0D%0A%20%20location%20%3D%20%7BHelsinki%2C%20FN%7D%2C%0D%0A%20%20owner%20%3D%20%7BAdministrator%7D%2C%0D%0A%20%20timestamp%20%3D%20%7B2009.03.08%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%40INPROCEEDINGS%7Bras-mor-models-06%2C%0D%0A%20%20author%20%3D%20%7BAwais%20Rashid%20and%20Ana%20Moreira%7D%2C%0D%0A%20%20title%20%3D%20%7BDomain%20Models%20Are%20%7BNOT%7D%20Aspect%20Free%7D%2C%0D%0A%20%20booktitle%20%3D%20%7BMoDELS%7D%2C%0D%0A%20%20year%20%3D%20%7B2006%7D%2C%0D%0A%20%20editor%20%3D%20%7BOscar%20Nierstrasz%20and%20Jon%20Whittle%20and%20David%20Harel%20and%20Gianna%20Reggio%7D%2C%0D%0A%20%20volume%20%3D%20%7B4199%7D%2C%0D%0A%20%20series%20%3D%20%7BLecture%20Notes%20in%20Computer%20Science%7D%2C%0D%0A%20%20pages%20%3D%20%7B155--169%7D%2C%0D%0A%20%20publisher%20%3D%20%7BSpringer%7D%2C%0D%0A%20%20bibdate%20%3D%20%7B2006-12-07%7D%2C%0D%0A%20%20bibsource%20%3D%20%7BDBLP%2C%20http%3A%2F%2Fdblp.uni-trier.de%2Fdb%2Fconf%2Fmodels%2Fmodels2006.html%23RashidM06%7D%2C%0D%0A%20%20isbn%20%3D%20%7B3-540-45772-0%7D%2C%0D%0A%20%20owner%20%3D%20%7Baljasser%7D%2C%0D%0A%20%20timestamp%20%3D%20%7B2008.09.16%7D%2C%0D%0A%20%20url%20%3D%20%7Bhttp%3A%2F%2Fdx.doi.org%2F10.1007%2F11880240_12%7D%0D%0A%7D)

If chuncks do not contain the `@` character, it will be more handy to use the `Regex.Split(input, pattern)` method:

```
string[] result = Regex.Split(input, @"[^}]*(?=@)");
```

If chuncks can contain the `@` character, you can make it more robust with a more descriptive lookahead:

```
string[] result = Regex.Split(input, @"[^}]*(?=@[A-Z]+{)");
```

or

```
string[] result = Regex.Split(input, @"\s*(?=@[A-Z]+{)");
```

Comment: it works fine on the above, but when i tried i got more results because it seems there are some records that have "@" in them, i got 283/243

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that your input does not finish by \n so your second record is not matched. You should put an alternation with $

This will get in group 1 the records:

```
@(.*?)^}(?:[\r\n]+|$)
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/cO9bE3/3)

Notice you have to use the `m` and `s` modifiers

Use this code:

```
Regex regex = new Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.Multiline | RegexOptions.Singleline);
MatchCollection mc = regex.Matches(bibFileContent);
List<String> results = new List<String>();
foreach (Group m in mc[0].Groups)
{
results.Add(m.Value);
}
```

Comment: Your regex is working, but it's not working on the code when i try it, i have used the MultilineOption

Comment: You have to use Multiline and SingleLine Option

Comment: I have tried this RegexOptions option = RegexOptions.Multiline | RegexOptions.Singleline; but still gives me zero matches

Comment: I edited the answer and I include the code I tested that matched

Comment: still not working, i have pasted the whole document content with your pattern http://regex101.com/r/cO9bE3/2

Comment: I found that the problem was the \n and it should be [\r\n]+ I updated the answer and include the code to insert the groups into a List

Comment: It's working now but there is minor problem. Last record is not splitted

Answer (score 1):

You could use a simple regex like this:

```
(@[^@]+)
```

**[Working demo](http://regex101.com/r/wQ3kD4/1)**

[image]

The idea is to match content that starts with @ and doesn't have another @. Btw, if you just want to match the pattern instead of capturing it just remove the capturin group:

```
@[^@]+
```