# c# Match multiple regex groups, keeping each match/word seperate

Tags: c#, .net, regex

Regex is currently doing my head in atm and unable to figure out how to obtain multiple match groups from a single string, while keeping the word results separate.

For E.g., I have a string 'GeForce TURBO-GTX1080-8G NVIDIA'.

I want to find each set of numbers in the string *(I know \d achieves a decimal match)*. Ie. 1080 and 8 (or if I could find them with their surround text as well, that would be better (GTX1080 & 8G).

I then want to be able to pull these out of the match and compare them with another string, but I want each word / match separate for comparison.

Ie. I want to run the same match against a different string such as 'GeForce TURBO-GTX1070-4G', (which will return 1070 and 4 etc.) and compare the matches against each other.

If I seem to use groups, ie. (\d)(\d\s), the matches don't seem to be successful.

I've looked around for answers and saw posts such as this...

[Multiple Group Matches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4970816/c-sharp-regex-group-multiple-captures)

And played around with regexstorm.net, however still having issues making that extra step.

Can anyone please shed some light on this?

Comment: Could you please precise what output you need? See [this demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=GeForce%5cs%2b%5cw%2b-(%5cw%2b)-(%5cw%2b)&i=GeForce+TURBO-GTX1080-8G+NVIDIA%0d%0aGeForce+TURBO-GTX1070-4G). What part will always be constant? What parts are variable?

Comment: Yes under the table, i need $1 and $2. Could explain to me how the regex works?

Comment: Also, will this only work if it has words next to the numbers? Is it possible to match only numbers as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to seek

```
GeForce\s+\w+-(\w+)-(\w+)
```

The [regex demo is available here](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=GeForce%5Cs%2B%5Cw%2B-(%5Cw%2B)-(%5Cw%2B)&i=GeForce%20TURBO-GTX1080-8G%20NVIDIA%0D%0AGeForce%20TURBO-GTX1070-4G).

**Pattern explanation**:

- `GeForce`  - a literal substring `GeForce`
- `\s+` - 1 or more whitespaces
- `\w+-` - 1+ word chars and a hyphen
- `(\w+)` - Group 1 capturing 1+ word chars
- `-` - a hyphen
  -`(\w+)` - Group 2 capturing 1+ word chars

To access the groups, use `Match.Groups[X].Value`.

[C# demo:](http://ideone.com/fOy21o)

```
var re = @"GeForce\s+\w+-(\w+)-(\w+)"; 
var str = "GeForce TURBO-GTX1080-8G NVIDIA\nGeForce TURBO-GTX1070-4Gi"; 
var res = Regex.Matches(str, re)
        .Cast<Match>()
        .Select(m => m.Groups.Cast<Group>().Skip(1).Select(g => g.Value) )
        .ToList();
foreach (var m in res)
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" : ", m));
```

If you also need to match digits there, use

```
GeForce\s+\w+-([^\W\d]*(\d+)[^\W\d]*)-([^\W\d]*(\d+)[^\W\d]*)
```

See [this regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=GeForce%5Cs%2B%5Cw%2B-(%5B%5E%5CW%5Cd%5D*(%5Cd%2B)%5B%5E%5CW%5Cd%5D*)-(%5B%5E%5CW%5Cd%5D*(%5Cd%2B)%5B%5E%5CW%5Cd%5D*)&i=GeForce%20TURBO-GTX1080-8G%20NVIDIA%0D%0AGeForce%20TURBO-GTX1070-4G). [The code](http://ideone.com/P9fV0X) will be the same as above.

Here, `\w+` are replaced with `[^\W\d]*(\d+)[^\W\d]*` that match:

- `[^\W\d]*` - zero or more word chars except digits (that is, `[\p{L}_]`, or `[\w-[\d]]`)
- `(\d+)` - Group X that captures one or more digits
- `[^\W\d]*` - ibid.

[image]

Comment: Thanks... ([^\W\d]*(\d+)[^\W\d]*)-([^\W\d]*(\d+)[^\W\d]*) is perfect for what I need, appreciate the help!

Comment: I found another, shorter way to grab the groups - `.Select(m => m.Groups.Cast<Group>().Skip(1).Select(g => g.Value) )`